# Is gt mongodb sources code setup doc location

Tags: geoserver, geotools

Is there any doc to setup the code for "geoserver-2.X-mongodb-plugin"?

Found the source code here but not in project structure,
https://dev.spidasoftware.com/artifactory/list/boundlessgeo/org/geotools/gt-mongodb/21.2/

.

Where we can find the git location for the same?

Answer (score 1):

The mongodb store is part of the GeoTools project, here:
https://github.com/geotools/geotools/tree/master/modules/plugin/mongodb

Generally speaking, anything that's not protocol specific, like feature and coverage stores, cascading support, rendering, referencing, style languages and so on, they are all found in GeoTools, while GeoServer has the protocols implementations and automation machinery (e.g., WMS, WFS, importer, output formats and the like).

Answer (score 0):

The GeoServer docs can be found at https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/mongodb/index.html